# Adding elements horizontally to the div

Tags: html, scroll, overflow

Currently I want the top part of my page to scroll on overflow-x but I can't do it because whenever I add elements to my div that allows horizontal scrolling, the elements that's supposed to be unseen(meaning goes out of div, horizontally), it goes on the bottom part of the div instead of the rigth side.
Here's my code

```
     <div class="headmenu">
        <a class="ui circular image border1px margin33 foodicon heightwidth"> <img src="../css/images/chicken.png" class="heightwidth"> </a>
        <a class="ui circular image border1px margin33 foodicon heightwidth"> <img src="../css/images/chicken.png" class="heightwidth"> </a>
        <a class="ui circular image border1px margin33 foodicon heightwidth"> <img src="../css/images/chicken.png" class="heightwidth"> </a>
        <a class="ui circular image border1px margin33 foodicon heightwidth"> <img src="../css/images/chicken.png" class="heightwidth"> </a>
        <a class="ui circular image border1px margin33 foodicon heightwidth"> <img src="../css/images/chicken.png" class="heightwidth"> </a>
        <a class="ui circular image border1px margin33 foodicon heightwidth"> <img src="../css/images/chicken.png" class="heightwidth"> </a>
    </div>
```

and here's my css

```
  .headmenu
     {
       position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height: 80px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;

    text-align:left;
    font-size:25px;
    background-color:#A6C462;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    z-index:15;

    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 trick you can use is to add a child div with a really large width to contain all your images horizontally, then cap the width of the outer most div.

http://jsfiddle.net/biz79/6jnc78z6/1/

HTML:

```
<div class="headmenu">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="ui circular image border1px margin33 foodicon heightwidth">
            <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/2542034/colorPicks/a400.png" class="heightwidth">
        </a>
...
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.headmenu {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.container {
    width:2500px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use display attribute like this

```
.headmenu {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height: 80px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;

    text-align:left;
    font-size:25px;
    background-color:#A6C462;
    vertical-align:text-bottom;
    z-index:15;

    display: inline-flex;

    overflow-x:scroll;
    overflow-y:hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6jnc78z6/

Comment: I tried adding that display:inline-flex but it "flex"-es my images inside for example if i add 8 chicken images they get resized so much just so all 8 will show. my goal is to show like 3 at a time then after scrolling left it will just show the next ones..

Comment: m not sure if i am understanding you correctly, your images are resized correctly ?, I think so you need define manually the image width to avoid this effect

Comment: I have manually defined the width and height of each image but inline-flex resizes them so they fit the width. Anyway someone has posted a solution below. Thank you still tho!